# In Adobe Creative Cloud, how can I view before installing a program or an update of it how many bytes it requires?

Tags: adobe-creative-cloud

In Adobe Creative Cloud, how can I view before installing a program or an update of it how many bytes it requires on my disk?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.